# Vue can not attach event listener

Tags: svg, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an `svg` with some elements in it, the complete code is in here [capture event](https://jsfiddle.net/ghostman/3xmfoL9k/2/), the aircraft image is positioned via `transform` attribute in such a way that it falls into the `image` with `href2`. The problem is Vue is unable to detect the click event on the aircraft image.
I can't seem to find a way to go around this. I want to be able to attach an event listener to the aircraft image regardless of where on the screen is located.

In jQuery solving these kind of situations is like a breeze of air, but with Vue seems to be a different story.

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1015px" height="580px" viewBox="-50 -50 1015 580" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" version="1.1" id="svg">
    <g @click="showFlightCard" v-for="(ge, index) in this.gEl" :key="index">
      <path :id="index+1" d="M 400 100 L 150 150" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
      <image :id="index" :href="href1" width="48" height="24" transform="translate(251,143)"></image>
    </g>
    <image x="250" y="10" width="522" height="402.452" id="e4_image" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" :href="href2" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:1px;fill:khaki;"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Here is the JS, for clarity I avoided the href in here due to 64 bit encoding, which is too long, please look at the jsfiddle which contains the href as well.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    showFlightCard: function (e) {
        console.log('Click')
    }
  },
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!',
    gEl: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    href1: 'look at the jsfiddle',
    href2: 'look at the jsfiddle'

  }
})
```

Comment: The click handler is attached. Click on the plane for example.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with a component that only has an svg tag as the root being returned. I solved it by wrapping the svg in a div.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the click listener on the path of the svg itself, or on the parent element of the svg. A click listener on the svg tag itself doesn't seem to fire events.